# Loop quantum gravity- is the critical density sufficient to form a 'black hole'?

Tags: black-holes, big-bang, loop-quantum-gravity

I think in loop quantum gravity the rate of expansion of the universe is found from:

$H^2=\frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho\left(1-\frac{\rho}{\rho_c}\right)$

And I was wondering whether the critical density $p_c$ in the equation would actually mean that all of the matter was condensed to within its Schwarzschild radius, but quantum effects make it bounce anyway? Or is the Schwarzschild radius never reached? (I think it must be considering observation suggest that there are black holes in our and other galaxies, and if the critical density was not great enough to reach the Schwarzschild radius then loop quantum gravity would predict that ordinary black holes cannot exist either, right?)

Comment: The universe is not described by the Schwarzschild metric so it has no Schwarzschild radius.

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks for your reply! I didn't phrase my question very well- although the universe has not Schwarzschild radius, there could be a point in the past when the matter density within the universe was so great that the density of matter exceeded its Schwarzschild radius there, right?

Comment: No, because the matter distribution in the universe is (approximately) homogeneous so the gravitational potential is the same everywhere. There is simply no concept of a Schwarzschild radius in these circumstances.

Comment: @JohnRennie Would that reasoning not apply to general relativity as well, so there would be no big bang singularity? It seems to me like it depends entirely on whether the universe is finite or infinite. A finite universe would not have the same matter distribution everywhere, so could it potentially have a Schwarzschild radius in this case?

Comment: The universe is described by the FLRW metric. This has a singularity at $t = 0$ (and for closed universes also at the recollapse time) however it has no horizons. A black hole is described by the Schwarzschild metric. This has a singularity at $r = 0$ and a horizon at $r = 2GM/c^2$.

Comment: A finite, i.e. closed, Friedmann universe is homogeneous and isotropic just like flat and open Friedmann universes. In the real universe at the current time the matter distribution is obviously not isotropic and locally black holes and their associated horizons can form. However if you look at the CMB (that dates from the recombination era) the universe was homogeneous to about one part in $10^5$. Because inhomogeneities grow with time we expect that near the Big Bang any conceivable universes would be almost exactly homogeneous.

Comment: @JohnRennie so in GR a singularity can form in a homogeneous and isotropic universe with no horizons?

Comment: Yes. If you want to understand this I'm afraid you'll have to get stuck in and learn about the FLRW metric. Without knowing your background I'm not sure what to recommend as a starting point. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) is **not** suitable for beginners. Incidentally your [other question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142050/increasing-matter-density-in-the-friedman-equations) also stems from misunderstanding the FLRW metric.

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm a high school student so I apologise if I have been asking stupid questions! I will try to learn about the FLRW metric and hopefully will post some better informed questions in the future...