# What prevented the early universe to become a black hole before inflation?

Tags: black-holes, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

I am an ignoramus on this subject, and I assume that these statements quoted from wikipedia are more or less accurate:(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflaton)

1) Prior to the expansion period, the inflaton field was at a higher-energy state.

2) Random quantum fluctuations triggered a phase transition whereby the inflaton field released its potential energy as matter and radiation as it settled to its lowest-energy state.

So, in the "classical/standard" theory (that means, no string theories, or newer ones), what was assumed to prevent the highly dense universe to become a black hole before inflation started?

Comment: @JohnRennie thanks, could you correct the link? it gous back to this same question

Comment: Oops, drat! Try [this link](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142084/loop-quantum-gravity-is-the-critical-density-sufficient-to-form-a-black-hole).

Comment: I wonder if it's worth writing another blog type question and answer on this topic ...

Comment: My comments to that question address the classical GR theory not LQG.

Comment: yes, sorry, I had missed that! I'll red it carefully and see if there is some issue that I do not get!

Comment: @JohnRennie I get that in an homogeneous universe the force of gravity is zero, but this is an unstable situation. I guess then that the answer is that inflation started before mass/energy inhomogeneities became high enough. Is that correct? (forget it, BenCrowell link actually answers that positively! thanks both of you

Comment: Local density fluctuations are required but not sufficient to form black holes. A black hole can only form/grow if the matter falling towards the local barycenter can also shed enough angular momentum and energy to actually reach the event horizon. The heating and fast rotation of large gravitating masses sets limits to how fast black holes can grow. If anything, theorists are scrambling for ideas, right now, how to get around the naive limits that follow from conservation laws.